# How to pass in arguments to a function (a dictionary item) inside the dictionary.get() method in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, keyerror

I'd like to replace multiple `if ... else` statements with a dictionary. The following code runs successfully and outputs `7` (i.e. the first argument is `'add'` which calls the `add` function declared inside the `my_dict` dictionary and gives it the arguments `n1` and `n2`):

```
def my_calc(operation, n1, n2):

    my_dict = {
        'add': lambda n1, n2: n1 + n2,
        'sub': lambda n1, n2: n1 - n2,
        'mul': lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2,
        'div': lambda n1, n2: n1 / n2
    }

    return my_dict[operation](n1, n2)

print(my_calc('add', 3, 4))
```

However, if I try to pass in an unfamiliar argument e.g. `my_calc('abc', 3, 4)`, it raises a `KeyError` because `abc` is not defined. For that reason, I'm using the `dictionary.get()` method.

How do I pass in arguments to a function returned by the `get()` method from a dictionary? The function should return the result of the operation performed on n1 and n2. I could easily have handled the error using `try ... except` but I'd like to do it using the `dictionary.get()` method and have the function return a default value if the operation is not in the dictionary.

```
def my_calc(operation, n1, n2):

    my_dict = {
        'add': lambda n1, n2: n1 + n2,
        'sub': lambda n1, n2: n1 - n2,
        'mul': lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2,
        'div': lambda n1, n2: n1 / n2
    }
    
    return my_dict.get(operation(n1, n2), "Default Value")

print(my_calc('abc', 3, 4))
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
File "<string>", line 10, in my_calc
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Is there any way I could pass in the arguments to the operation inside the `get()` method?

List item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first problem is that you're calling the operation, which is a string. You want to call the *result* of the `get()` method instead. That means the arguments go outside (after) the `get()` parentheses.

Then, to provide a default behavior, the default value in `get()` should also be a function. It just doesn't need to do anything with its arguments. You can use a lambda like you have for the others.

```
return my_dict.get(operation, lambda n1, n2: "Default Value")(n1, n2)
```

If you want, you can store the default function in your dictionary. That way they're all together. We'll use `None` as the key since that 1) makes sense (there is no operation) and 2) can never be entered by a user.

```
my_dict = {
    None:  lambda n2, n2: "Default value",
    'add': lambda n1, n2: n1 + n2,
    'sub': lambda n1, n2: n1 - n2,
    'mul': lambda n1, n2: n1 * n2,
    'div': lambda n1, n2: n1 / n2
}
```

Then...

```
return my_dict.get(operation, my_dict[None])(n1, n2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Both the solutions are awesome but I don't understand why the default behaviour in the `get()` should be a function. And should it only be a lambda?

Comment: _"I don't understand why the default behaviour in the get() should be a function."_: It needs to be a _callable_, because you _call_ the result of `.get()` (or dictionary indexing `my_dict[operation]`). If you simply returned your default value from `.get()`, you wouldn't be able to call that default value like you call the other functions, which would throw an error

Comment: It needs to be a function (or other callable) because you're going to call it. `my_dict.get()` gets functions from the dictionary, so all values need to be callable in the same way. `my_dict.get()` does not call the function, you do that after you get the function.